# In Emacs AUCTex how can I change the pdf output viewer to use the doc-view-mode inside Emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers

I am using Debian 11 and would really like to be able to use a internal to Emacs PDF viewer, as it seems it can be acomplished with doc-view-mode inside Emacs, there are some posts about this from years ago but none of them seem to have a answer. I am used to editors that have built-in viewers and I really like Emacs, also for me it would be very cumbersome to use Zathura or Evince as a viewer in another window outside Emacs, I would much more like to use a internal window in Emacs with a buffer in doc-view-mode, no matter how "limited" doc-view-mode is. I got to the point where I can change the (output-pdf) Viewer to a few limited choices in TeX Command TeX View customization group, but I cannot seem to find DocView or doc-view-mode as a option.

Comment: Which Emacs version and which auctex version?

Answer (score 2):

1-Install the `pdf-tools` package from `melpa` or `melpa-stable'

2- Add the following lines to your initialization file:

```
(pdf-tools-install)
(custom-set-variables
;; ...
'(TeX-view-program-selection
   '(((output-dvi has-no-display-manager)
      "dvi2tty")
     ((output-dvi style-pstricks)
      "dvips and gv")
     (output-dvi "xdvi")
     (output-pdf "PDF Tools")
     (output-html "xdg-open")))
 ;; ...
  )
```